# Error cannot open file libcimt.lib after upgrading c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have upgraded an old c++ project which contained .dsw and .dsp files with Visual Studio 2019 but after some adjustments I get this error when compiling 'LNK1104 cannot open file 'libcimt.lib''.

Do i need to change something in my project?

Comment: Does that old project link to some other old libraries?

Comment: lnk1104 means linker cannot found the lib. Did you have the lib or set directory in  project's properties-> Linker -> Additional Lib Directories?